# Can JFrames be put in a parent window?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jinternalframe

I have a project which creates several JFrames and shows them as separate windows. This can be quite confusing, so I want to collect all these frames in a parent window.

I am aware of the concept of JInternalFrame which would certainly work in principle, but the project is quite large, and the JFrames rather complex, so converting them individually to JInternalFrame seems more or less unfeasible to me (particularly due to JInternalFrame behaving a little differently in some respects such as mouse events).

Is there a way to take the JFrames themselves and put them in a parent window? (Or is there another solution I'm not thinking of?)

Comment: Just take their [*contentPanes*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#getContentPane%28%29) and add them to the parent JFrame. This should be much easier.

Comment: You mean like having several contentPanes in one JFrame? Does that even work?

Comment: A "contenPane" of a JFrame is just a normal `JPanel` and yes, you can have several panels in on JFrame (on its own contentPane).

Comment: Okay, didn't know that. I think I'll have to read a bit before I can try the suggestions, but thank's for the good start!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no.  This is why we generally discourage extending from `JFrame` (or top level containers) directly.  You need to try a move the content out of the `JFrame` to something like `JPanel`.  This will allow you to make better decisions about how to present the content.

The simplest solution is to go through your code and replace `extends JFrame` with `extends JPanel` and correct for any compiler errors that it produces.  You could also add a `static` method that wraps an instance of the container into a `JFrame` should you need it.

Comment: Okay, I will try that. (That's where the legacy bites you in the ass... ;-) ) But  what do I do with the JPanels then? (I'm not very good in GUI programming, to be honest.)

Comment: What about child forms?

Comment: You simply add them to what ever container you want, like another `JPanel` or `JInternalFrame` or `JTabbedPane` or use them in a `CardLayout` or even add them to a `JFrame` or `JDialog` as required

Comment: @lukas.coenig I wrote it, but if you need a wee hand getting started on JPanel, take a look at this site : http://www.macs.hw.ac.uk/cs/java-swing-guidebook/ - it's 6 years old, but still good :)

Comment: like MIDI (I think) forms. Such as Photoshop which has sub-forms for each file you open. and then you can switch between windows.

Comment: @Salivan Yep, `JInternalFrame`s, but you'd still need a `JPanel` as the base component (as a convention), with that you get the flexibility to make decisions like using `JTabbedPane`, `CardLayout`, compound views or what ever ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer can you add an example for this because I'm also looking for this answer it'll be really great help if you add an exaple with your code

Comment: @Luffy Example of what?